# Android - Preferences that work on both 2.2 and 4.0

Tags: sharedpreferences, preferenceactivity, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, android-2.2-froyo, android-2.3-gingerbread

I want to create user preferences for my application.  How do I create preferences that work both on 2.2 and 4.0?

The example provided for PreferenceActivity in Android Help requires API 11 and above. There is an option to apply @TargetApi at onCreate or the class level only.

So is the best practise to create to separate PreferenceActivity classes - one for API 11 and above & other for API 8 & above - and call the one based on the version of android the user is on?